# How to get all posts except for one post from a certain custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, loop

I have created a custom post type named `rooms`. I would like to get all `rooms` posts except for the one with the post id `164`, and display it using the code below:

```
<div class="room-container container room-grid">
    <div class="heading-box">
        <h2>rooms</h2>
    </div>

  <?php 
    $my_query   = new WP_Query('post_type=rooms&posts_per_page=-1'); 
    $c          = 1;

    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $my_query->the_post();
        $thumb   = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb );
        $content = get_the_content();
  ?>

    <div class="room-box col-xs-6">
        <div class="img-container">
            <img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" alt="rooms">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">More Details</a>
        </div>

        <div class="details">
            <div class="title">
                <a href="#"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>
            </div>

            <div class="desc">
                <?php echo substr( $content, 0, 200 ); ?>...
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

  <?php $c++; endwhile; ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the working code. rooms doesnt need 'rooms'. Thankyou friends..

```
<?php
    $my_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => rooms, 'post__not_in' => array(164)) );
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
    $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb);
    $content = get_the_content();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `post__not_in` Argument of wp_query like this

```
$query= new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'rooms', 'post__not_in' => array(164));
```

Answer (score 1):

[WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) has a ***ton*** of indices you can define. The one you need is `posts__not_in` under [Post and Page Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) section. It would look like this in practice:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'rooms',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'posts__not_in'  => array( 164 ),
) );
```

This will get all posts in the `rooms` post type with the exception of `post_id` 164.